# Laravel do i need two controllers to handel two store functions?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Basically what i want to do is that 1 Controller handels two store functions called like this:

```
public function singleupload(){

..some code
}
```

and

```
public function multiupload(){
..some code too
}
```

as i continued to define the routes (get/post)

```
Route::get('/MultiUpload', 'controller@MultiUpload');
Route::get('/SingleUpload', 'controller@SingleUpload');

Route::post('/MultiUpload', 'controller@storeMulti');
Route::post('/SingleUpload', 'controller@storeSingle');
```

and as i tried to post some data to my database it tells me that there is no 'store' function. So i opened the docs and found this:

```
POST    /photos store   photos.store
```

So my question is can i create two store functions in one controller or do i have to create a different one so every route has its own controller with its own store function?

Comment: no you can handel in same controller but it is not recommended to pull all function in one controller

Comment: Okay thanks i guess i create a second one then

Comment: if it is in same feature function you should put in one controller just follow good naming convention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some things wrong.

First of all follow **[Repository Pattern](https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce)**.

You should always write all common functions in Repository which can be accessible in entire Project.

You should use controller only to fetch the request from the Route and pass all the logic to the Repository.

These Process will help you reduce all you coding lines.

Hope this helps !!!

cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

NO you don't need to create new Controller. You can add new action for this.

But it also, depends on the how is your application functionality.

Normally, i personally recommended to create generic function or traits or add the functionality in base controller.

Answer (score -2):

you can handle multiple store functions in one controller there is no need to create 2 different controllers.